# R. Split column with sequential values into 2 columns with consecutive start and end positions

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame A like this one:

```
CHR POS X Y
1 447892 0.994 0.994
1 651929 0.988 1.982
1 741566 0.982 2.964
1 741566+n 
... 
2 2000 0.347 0.347
2 3444 0.421 0.768
2 3444+m
...
```

Here, observations are grouped by CHR, whereas POS has an ordered sequence of values. Y is the cumulative sum of X. For each row in CHR, I want to split POS into two columns N1 and N2 obtaining something like this:

```
CHR N1 N2 X Y 
1 447892 651929 0.994 0.994
1 651929 741566 0.988 1.982
1 741566 741566+n 0.982 2.964
2 2000 3444 0.347 0.347
2 3444 3444+m 0.421 0.768
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to take the `lead` of the 'POS' after grouping by 'CHR'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(CHR) %>% 
   transmute(X, Y, N1 = POS, N2 = lead(POS)) %>%
   na.omit
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   CHR [2]
#    CHR     X     Y     N1     N2
#  <int> <dbl> <dbl>  <int>  <int>
#1     1 0.994 0.994 447892 651929
#2     1 0.988 1.98  651929 741566
#3     1 0.982 2.96  741566 741566
#4     2 0.347 0.347   2000   3444
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(CHR = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), POS = c(447892L, 
651929L, 741566L, 741566L, 2000L, 3444L), X = c(0.994, 0.988, 
0.982, 0.55, 0.347, 0.421), Y = c(0.994, 1.982, 2.964, 2.54, 
0.347, 0.768)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```